# Not able to embed certain *.mov files with <video> tags

Tags: html5-video

I am getting from a service some links to *.mov videos, but their url has query string parameters and I don't know if this is the reason but I am not able to embed them on the page.
This is a source of one of them for example:
http://cache1.asset-cache.net/xd/457430254.mov?v=1&c=IWSAsset&k=2&d=2549FB43098C7F200F7C309C560BA2808EED8012893D117345EEB6BCEF0E7040&b=RQ==

I did try to remove the parameters but then the video doesn't work.

Please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mjdw34as/) which contains this code:

```
<div>This works:</div>
<video autoplay src="http://www.kin.ucalgary.ca/courses/knes381/sample.mov">
</video>

<div>This doesn't work:</div>
<video autoplay src="http://cache1.asset-cache.net/xd/457430254.mov?v=1&c=IWSAsset&k=2&d=2549FB43098C7F200F7C309C560BA2808EED8012893D117345EEB6BCEF0E7040&b=RQ==">
</video>
```

Why can't I embed them on the page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should know that HTML5 `<video>` element has a limited number of supported video format, for more infos take a look here : [Media formats supported by the HTML audio and video elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats). So for your first video, It's has the `MPEG-4 AVC` (or `H264`) video format with `AAC` as audio format and It's supported by HTML5 video tag. On the other side, the second video has as video format the `Sorenson 3` and `ADPCM`as audio format, so it's not supported by HTML5 video element.